# How to solve the malformed arrow value error?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
const removeChatTyping = (data) => {
    getTypingMessages(data).fadeOut(function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
```

I don't need the "fadeout" part so I took it out like this:

```
const removeChatTyping = (data) => {
    getTypingMessages(data) => {
      $(this).remove();
    };
  }
```

but I get an error that says malformed arrow. How can I take the fade out part smoothly?

I'd appreciate any answers that can lead me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove it immediately when the function is called, then you don't need a callback (or attempted callback), just call `.remove()` immediately.

```
const removeChatTyping = (data) => {
    getTypingMessages(data);
    $(this).remove();
}
```